# vs Addin failing trying to Execute command

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, add-in

I have VS2012 professional and would very much like my finely honed tests to run at the end of a build.

I thought I could do by writing an addin quite simply. So I have this in a c# addin.

```
public void OnConnection(object app, ext_ConnectMode cM, object aI, ref Array cust) {
    _applicationObject = (DTE2)app;
    _addInInstance = (AddIn)aI;
    if (_applicationObject != null) {
        _bldevents = _applicationObject.Events.BuildEvents;
        _bldevents.OnBuildDone += _bldevents_OnBuildDone;
    }
}

void _bldevents_OnBuildDone(vsBuildScope Scope, vsBuildAction Action) {
    try {
        _applicationObject.ExecuteCommand("TestExplorer.RunAllTests");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        string d = " + " + e.HResult;
        Clipboard.SetText(e.Message + " ~ " + e.HResult);
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
}
```

However when I do a build I get the error **Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component. ~ -2147467259**

ExecuteCommand work on stuff like File.NewFile run TestExplorer.RunAllTests in the command window with no problems.

Is there some setup that needs doing or have ms somehow stymied the behaviour because they want me to bankrupt myself and get the ultimate version ;)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like TestExplorer.RunAllTests performs build first, your _bldevents_OnBuildDone is called again, TestExplorer.RunAllTests is called again and second time it throws the exception.

You can add the IsCommandAvailable check to prevent this recursion:

```
if (IsCommandAvailable("TestExplorer.RunAllTests"))
                _applicationObject.ExecuteCommand("TestExplorer.RunAllTests");

bool IsCommandAvailable(string command) 
{
    Commands2 commands = (Commands2)(_applicationObject.Commands);
    if (commands == null)
        return false;

    Command dte_command = commands.Item(command, 0);
    if (dte_command == null)
        return false;

    return dte_command.IsAvailable;
}
```